# Working with css on vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm reading the chapter 8 on book of vaadin and I cannot understand how define a css style  for each components. I did the customization on styles.scss but all customization went to all components and I don't wanna this.

example

```
HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
HorizontalLayout hMainLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
```

I want that hLayout has a background image and hMainLayout no has.

I try this, but not work.

```
.v-horizontallayout-hLayout {
     background:url("myimage.jpg");
}

.v-horizontallayout-hMainLayout {
     background: none;
}
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to add something little to users 'default locale' answer:

There's also a method called `addStyleName(String)` which is in some cases better especially when you don't want to replace any previous user-defined styles.

BTW:
You can apply more than one styles with `setStyleName(String)` / `addStyleName(String)` by invoking it like this:

```
hLayout.setStyleName("aLayout bLayout cLayout"); // replaces any previous styles
hLayout.addStyleName("dLayout eLayout fLayout"); // add styles without any replacement
```

Answer (score 4):

Vaadin doesn't define styles based on java variable names.

You can use [Component.setStyleName](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Component.html#setStyleName%28java.lang.String%29) to apply custom style name to your component:

```
HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
hLayout.setStyleName("hLayout");
```

Then you can match style `v-horizontallayout-hLayout`